# localization and route:resource does not work

Tags: php, localization, routes, laravel-5

I have [mcamara/laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) via composer installed. This works fine. I mainly use it  through `http://url-to-laravel/en`, the added language locale `en` on the domain root.

Furthermore I have a scaffolding working with [mitulgolakiya/laravel-api-generator](https://github.com/mitulgolakiya/laravel-api-generator), as well installed via composer.

This works as well fine. I have created a scaffold for `Order`. When I now combine scaffold with the localization I run into trouble.

Calling `http://url-to-laravel/en/orders` results in:

```
 ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 296: Route [orders.create] not defined. 
(View: /var/www/apps/foobar/l5/resources/views/orders/index.blade.php)
```

Calling `http://url-to-laravel/orders` works fine.

I think I have to tweak how the routes are called in blade or how the routes itself are configured, but I do not know how?

**How do I get the scaffolded routes working with the localization?**

#### app/Http/routes.php

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()], function() {

  Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('start');
  });

});

Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()], function() {
  Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController');

  Route::get('orders/{id}/delete', [
    'as' => 'orders.delete',
    'uses' => 'OrderController@destroy',
  ]);
});
```

#### resources/views/orders/index.blade.php

```html
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    @include('flash::message')

    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="pull-left">Orders</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: 25px"
        href="{!! route('orders.create') !!}">Add New</a> <!-- ERROR LINE -->
    </div>

    <div class="row"> 
        @if($orders->isEmpty())
            <div class="well text-center">No Orders found.</div>
        @else
            @include('orders.table')
        @endif
    </div>
    @include('common.paginate', ['records' => $orders])
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by stating the routes generated by `Route:resource()` manually in the `app/Http/routes.php`. Now I can access my scaffold with: `http://url-to-laravel/orders` and `http://url-to-laravel/en/orders`.

#### php artisan route:list

```
+----------+----------------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Method   | URI                  | Name           | Action                                       |
+----------+----------------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------+
| GET|HEAD | /                    |                | Closure                                      |
| POST     | orders               | orders.store   | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@store   |
| GET|HEAD | orders               | orders.index   | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@index   |
| GET|HEAD | orders/create        | orders.create  | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@create  |
| GET|HEAD | orders/{id}/delete   | orders.delete  | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@destroy |
| DELETE   | orders/{orders}      | orders.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@destroy |
| PATCH    | orders/{orders}      |                | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@update  |
| GET|HEAD | orders/{orders}      | orders.show    | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@show    |
| PUT      | orders/{orders}      | orders.update  | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@update  |
| GET|HEAD | orders/{orders}/edit | orders.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@edit    |
+----------+----------------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

This I used to create my routes manually:

#### app/Http/routes.php

```
// ...
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()], function() {

  Route::get( 'orders', ['as' => 'orders.index', 'uses' => 'OrderController@index'] );
  Route::get( 'orders/create', ['as' => 'orders.create', 'uses' => 'OrderController@create'] );
  Route::post( 'orders', ['as' => 'orders.store', 'uses' => 'OrderController@store'] );
  Route::get( 'orders/{orders}', ['as' => 'orders.show', 'uses' => 'OrderController@show'] );
  Route::get( 'orders/{orders}/edit', ['as' => 'orders.edit', 'uses' => 'OrderController@edit'] );
  Route::put( 'orders/{orders}', ['as' => 'orders.update', 'uses' => 'OrderController@update'] );

  //Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController'); # does not work with prefix for Laravellocalization

  Route::get('orders/{id}/delete', [
    'as' => 'orders.delete',
    'uses' => 'OrderController@destroy',
  ]);
});
```

Furthermore I had to adapt the `edit.blade.php` file generated by [mitulgolakiya/laravel-api-generator](https://github.com/mitulgolakiya/laravel-api-generator).

The `'method' => 'patch'` had to be changed to `'method' => 'put'`. As the with `patch` a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` will be raised.

#### resources/views/orders/edit.blade.php

```
{!! Form::model($order, ['route' => ['orders.update', $order->id], 'method' => 'put']) !!}
```

Comment: i think it not better because we use resource to save lots of routes in web.php and other things

Answer (score 0):

To add 10 lines to your code is  not the solution.
This is the way:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1616